# Which dataset do I use for calculating the Calinski Harabasz index?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pca

I am doing a Clusteranalysis on the most significant componants.
In order to find the number of clusters I apply the Calinski Harabasz index. I have two questions:
Do I need to normalize the components before clustering. I haven't done it so far as the variance expresses the importance of a component.
Concerning the CH-index, do  I calculate it on the original data or do I calculate it on the output of my pca function? I try to clarify:

```
pca <- prcomp(data_scaled)
pca$x
```

Here I use pca$x for the cluster analysis.Should I use the data_scaled dataset or the pca$x dataset for calculating the CH-index?

Comment: See the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clusterCrit/vignettes/clusterCrit.pdf) of package `clusterCrit`.

Comment: ok, that actually helped a lot. I need to calculate it on the original (scaled) Data.